# error: putText is not a member of CV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I can not use the function putText. I get the compilation error "putText is not member of CV" or "putText is not declared in this scope". 
These are the libraries I am including:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "core.hpp"
#include "highgui.hpp"
#include "imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "cv.h"
```

and that's how I am calling it:

```
cv::putText(frame,"REC",Point(0,60),2,2,Scalar(0,0,255));
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: More detail please. How are you calling it?

Comment: Maybe you need cv::putText()

Comment: I tried both. without 'cv::' it says that the function is not declared in this scope

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`putText` has been moved to [imgproc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576&gsc.tab=0) module in OpenCV 3 (previously it was in `core` module).

So you need to:

```
#include "imgproc.hpp"
```

You can include `opencv.hpp` to avoid this kind of problems, since it will include all headers for you.